# How do i run an interactive python script 24/7 on a windows server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vps, python, remote

The script needs to be started manually from a virtual desktop connection and then let it work 24/7. The problem is that when i close the remote desktop connection the script stops. As long as my script interacts with a browser window in the virtual desktop i cant run the script as a windows service.

VPS: Microsoft Windows Server 2019 with Desktop Experience Locale English AMI provided by Amazon

Comment: Does it absolutely need to run on Windows, or talk to a browser?

Comment: Not necessarily on windows, but it interacts with the browser

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to create a Windows service running as an SYSTEM_.* type user.You can do this with sc command:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/251192/how-to-create-a-windows-service-by-using-sc-exe